Where did she go? + She left her food on the burner
Would the following sentence work if someone left their food on the burner (and the burner was still on) and they were nowhere to be seen?

Where did she go leaving her food on the burner like that?

To me it sounds a little weird and I think that it would be better to break it up into two separate sentences. There are, however, sentences in English where the preposition is dropped. Although, I will acknowledge that those sentences aren't two sentences mashed together, instead they are a single sentence with the preposition dropped.
I was wondering if there was a way of doing that in English?
Similar sentences:

Where did she go leaving her kids behind like that?

Another sentence that doesn't work in English:

Where did X go leaving their food? (As in: Where did they go without finishing their food/meal (or)in the middle of dinner)


Where did they go leaving their phone behind? (Where did they go? They left their phone behind.)

I know that the last two sentences definitely don't work as they are written in English but I just wanted to provide more context to where my head is at with this question.
Thank you!

This is an interesting question! I'll start by saying that "Where did she go leaving her food on the burner like that?" would sound completely normal to me in spoken American English.

That sentence is fine, but I think your instinct to split it into two sentences when written is good. When speaking this sentence you can use emphasis and subtle pauses to help the meaning. Without that the sentence has a certain amount of cognitive strain.

As a BrE speaker, I would say "Where has she gone?"

which preposition was dropped? (that may be right. but I just see the sentence as-it-is).

@mamster Would this sentence with the exact same construction ever be heard in spoken English?

@Sam I assumed that the preposition that was dropped was "after".

The sentence is similar to "Where has she gone after leaving the burner on?" (Inquiring where someone has gone because they left the burner on)

Maybe. I don't know. Consider this sentence "The woman, leaving the food on the burner for a moment, ran out into the hallway to see what the noise was."   It's possible to generate similar constructions without "after".

@Sam So does the sentence in my original post sound natural to you? And more importantly do you think that someone might actually frame the question that way? Or is it almost always going to be broken up into two separate sentences or perhaps be expressed in a different way altogether (depending on the situation)? Can you imagine yourself using that sentence?

Does it sound natural to me? I guess it sounds alright in spoken English. I probably wouldn't write that way in an official essay.

To me, the context is a little off. I think it's missing another expression that typically proceeds the phrase in question. For example, I would expect to hear:

Where did she go? The nerve of her, leaving her food on the burner like that.
Where did she go? And who does she think she is, leaving her food on the burner like that?

But it's probably find the way you have it, too. It's very informal, so you have  a lot of leeway.
